# Arch-Linux: no boot messages

Tags: arch-linux

I'm fairly new to Arch-Linux so maybe this Question is a little bit ridiculous.
If I boot the "Live-CD" of Arch-Linux, I see which services are successfully started, indicated by a green [OK] message.

After installing Arch-Linux I only get a blank Screen till the login-prompt appears.

What should I do to display these messages again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the quiet option from the kernel line in your boot/loader...

Comment: it worked thanks...so obvious, shame on me^^